# The function of typedef block in IOS

Tags: ios, block, typedef

Today I want to learn how to use typedef to define a block type. I read the related content from "IOS developer library". But I feel confused about some statement of the sentences.
As an example, you can define a type for a simple block with no arguments or return value, like this:

```
typedef void (^XYZSimpleBlock)(void);
```

You can then use your custom type for method parameters or when creating block variables:

```
XYZSimpleBlock anotherBlock = ^{

    ...

};

- (void)beginFetchWithCallbackBlock:(XYZSimpleBlock)callbackBlock {

   ...

   callbackBlock();

}
```

Custom type definitions are particularly useful when dealing with blocks that return blocks or take other blocks as arguments. Consider the following example:

```
void (^(^complexBlock)(void (^)(void)))(void) = ^ (void (^aBlock)(void))   {

   ...

   return ^{

      ...

   };

};
```

The complexBlock variable refers to a block that takes another block as an argument (aBlock) and returns yet another block.

Rewriting the code to use a type definition makes this much more readable:

```
XYZSimpleBlock (^betterBlock)(XYZSimpleBlock) = ^ (XYZSimpleBlock aBlock) {

   ...

   return ^{

    ...

   };

}
```

The question I want to ask is that how to convert the expression from

```
void (^(^complexBlock)(void (^)(void)))(void)
```

to

```
XYZSimpleBlock (^betterBlock)(XYZSimpleBlock) = ^ (XYZSimpleBlock aBlock)
```

?

Comment: You can try with: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/ .

Comment: @longpham, I see the web page of the above link, but I am still confused with the transform